# How a mobile platform can be used with ROS Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a mobile platform.
It can move and read odometry information by using C program.
How to package it can be used with ROS Navigation and SLAM .
Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247716/how-a-mobile-platform-can-be-used-with-ros-navigation/) by [Nelson Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28487/nelson-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do not you read the wiki page? It is clear and well done. Start from [Navigation Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2016-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0